# Can't understand why $ doesn't match on this list

Tags: regex

I've always struggled with getting regex to work. Better put, why is is my regex pattern not successfully matching a string. Usually I'm using regex in bash scripts, find and send commands.

As I understood it, `$` at the end of a regex pattern will match lines that end with the pattern.Can anyone explain why this isn't matching correctly.

**Regex Pattern**

`\.\/.*\.moved$`

> ./Library.moved*
>
> ./.cpan/build/ExtUtils-MakeMaker-6.96-u4aD1K/t/ZPfMx0qYVS

However using a `^` works producing a match.

**Regex Pattern**

`^\.\/.*\.moved`

> **./Library.moved**
>
> ./.cpan/build/ExtUtils-MakeMaker-6.96-u4aD1K/t/ZPfMx0qYVS

Comment: It works for me. Perhaps your string has hidden characters at end, like \r\n or a single space. You could try `\.\/.*\.moved\s?\s?$` to see if that's the case

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the regex - [it works](http://rubular.com/r/tt1yEaqxNK). There must be some whitespace after "moved" in your input.

Comment: @Bohemian Thanks for the sanity check. Oddly I get no match in OS X find of using this regex tester https://regex101.com/r/mE9kS6/1 but clearly it works with that Ruby regex tester you suggested.

Comment: @juliushibert: With multiline mode, [your example works](https://regex101.com/r/mE9kS6/2). `$` is not always the end of line (as in Ruby). In most languages, it is the end of the string, and you need the multiline flag to make it match the end of the line.

Comment: @stribizhev Thanks for the clarification. I can't find out if there's a way to set multiline mode when using bash find. Is there a way? It appears there's a multiline flag -M in grep, but not in find.

Comment: I am not sure I can help with `find`, but perhaps you do not even need it. Try `\.\/.*\.moved(\n|$)` (or `\.\/.*\.moved\(\n\|$\)`).